# SVN: Is it possible to pull an entire folder from the repository as it existed on a specific date and time?

Tags: svn

Let's say we don't use the tags/branches/trunk repository structure and want to get latest on an entire folder as it existed at a specific date and time.  Ideally, SVN would recursively query all files and folders in the specified parent folder and "rebuild" the entire architecture based on the files returned from the query.  This would eliminate having to keep a history of every version and every bug fix in an application.

Can SVN do anything like this?

Comment: Having thought about it, this may be difficult because you'd have to rely on a constant date and time.  If the server time ever becomes different by even a few minutes, this could possibly throw off the query.  Crap, did I just answer my own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could checkout based on a date:

`svn co -r {2011-12-01} REPO_URL path/to/new/working/copy`

However thats not specific to a time, its the revision at start of the date. Youd be better off using tags.